# Lodash: Union by property of an array of objects

Tags: lodash

I have an array of objects that has an array property that I am trying to union together. I have already solved the problem with the code below, which shows what I am trying to do:

```
var dest = [];
_.forEach(parentArray, function (parentItem) {
    _.forEach(parentItem.arrayProperty, function(arrayPropertyItem) {
        dest.push(arrayPropertyItem);
    });
});
```

This works fine. But I am wondering if lodash has any shortcut methods for this. I tried using unionBy/unionWith, but it doesnt seem to have the intended result. Instead simply giving me back the parentArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) and [flatten](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatten). If I understand your data structure  (and what you are trying to accomplish) you should be able to do something like this

```
var dest = _.flatMap(parentArray, function(item) {
  return item.arrayProperty;
});
```

If necessary you can use the `_.flatten` on `item.arrayProperty` depending on what you are trying to accomplish. If the `arrayProperty` contains an array of arrays the output will have a nested array as well. If it goes any deeper you may need to use [flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flattenDeep).

```js
var parentArray = [{item: 'one', children: [1, 2, 3]}, {item: 'two', children: [4, 5, 6]}];

var dest = _.flatMap(parentArray, function(item) {
  return item.children;
});

console.log(dest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can play around with it by having nested arrays in the `children` property and adding `_.flatten` if necessary.

Comment: Favor on-site stack snippet over off-site services like JSBin, jsfiddle, etc.

Comment: Made the changes but now OP will have a harder time playing with the code to gain a better understanding :(

Comment: OP can play with the code on whichever setup he prefers. SO answers shouldn't take that into account.

Comment: Oh and thank you for taking the time to improve your answer!

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Not sure how I didn't notice that method in the docs, the name perhaps is a little misleading. UnionBy seemed more appropriate name wise haha!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `flatMap` with the *name* of the nested property as second argument:

```
_.flatMap(parentArray, 'arrayProperty')
```

```js
var parentArray = [{
    arrayProperty: [1, 2]
}, {
    arrayProperty: [3, 4]
}];

console.log( _.flatMap(parentArray, 'arrayProperty') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```